# Show that $\int_0^\infty 1/f'=\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality

Suppose that $\space f$ is positive and monotone increasing on $(0,\infty)$, $\space f \in AC[a,b]$(absolutely continuous) for every finite interval [a,b], and there is a constant $C>0$ such that $\space f(x)\leq Cx^2$ for all $x>0$. Prove that $\int_0^\infty1/f'=\infty$.

What I got is:

Fix $\space 0<a<b<\infty$,
\begin{align}
b-a=\int_a^b1=\int_a^bf'^{1/2}\cdot f'^{-1/2}&=|\langle f'^{1/2},f'^{-1/2}\rangle|\\
&\leq \|f'^{1/2}\|_2\cdot\|f'^{-1/2}\|_2
\end{align}
Rearrange the inequality and take square of both sides to get:
\begin{align}
\|f'^{-1/2}\|_2^2 & \geq \frac{(b-a)^2}{\|f'^{1/2}\|_2^2}\\
\int_a^b f'^{-1} & \geq \frac{(b-a)^2}{\int_a^b f'}=\frac{(b-a)^2}{f(b)-f(a)}
\end{align}
And I got stuck here. I think the next step should be using the assumption $\space f(x)≤Cx^2$ to show that by letting $a\rightarrow0$ and $b\rightarrow \infty$, the integral will go infinity. But I don't know how.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say $[a,b]$ you mean $a>0?$

Comment: Yes, since the $f$ is not defined on 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: By Jensen,

$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \frac{1}{f'} \ge \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f'}.$$

Comment: Form your inequality I can only see that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1 {f'} \geq \frac 1 C$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  You actually get $\int_0^x 1/f' \ge 1/c$ for any $x>0,$ no matter how small.

Comment: Great! I didn't expect the answer to be so simple!

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of Jensen.

Comment: But I still have the same problem with @KaviRamaMurthy. Since $\int_0^x 1/f'$ has to start at 0, I don't see how I can extend it to $\infty$. Is there any Theorem that I am missing?

Comment: You may be missing this: The problem is near $0,$ not $\infty.$ No integrable function $g$ can satisfy $\int_0^x g \ge 1/c$ for all $x.$

Comment: Oh right! Thanks again!

Comment: @zhw.: Why can no integrable function satisfy $\int_0^x g \geq 1/c$?

Comment: @WolfgangKrull Because if $g$ is integrable, then $|g\chi_{(0,x)}|\le |g|$ and $|g\chi_{(0,x)}|\to 0$ everywhere. Therefore $\int_0^x g \to 0$ by DCT.